# Append DOM element below active ui-route anchor

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

**ui-router** offers a nifty feature for anchor tags, [ui-sref-active](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active). It adds a class when the associated route or any child route is active.

I'd like to append an element to the DOM using the same rule, e.g.:

```
<ul class="books" ng-controller="TreeController">
    <li ng-repeat="book in books">
        <a ui-sref="book({id: book.id})" ui-sref-active="active">
            {{book.title}}
        </a>
        <!-- NG-IF BELOW IS THE CODE IN QUESTION -->
        <ul class="chapters" ng-if="UI-SREF-ACTIVE">
            <li ng-repeat="chapter in chapters(book.id)">
```

**What can I replace `ng-if="UI-SREF-ACTIVE"` with?**

I can't use the CSS adjacent-sibling rule `a.active + ul { display: block; }`. I must wait to create the element because `chapters(book.id)` must lazy-load.

I also can't use `$state.is('book',{id:book.id})`. It doesn't return true for child routes.

Comment: Can you use $state.includes?

Comment: OK, I think you are right, so `ng-if="$state.includes('book', {id: book.id})"` may do it, where I've set `$scope.$state = $state` injected in my controller. Is that what you are thinking?

Comment: Would there be a shortcut to use the [`includedByState`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.filter:includedByState) filter in an `ng-if` evaluation? I'm pretty new to angular and I don't know where different components get automatically evaluated.

Comment: Yeah, the first was what I was thinking but the filter may work too...I'm not really sure how to structure that though.